# Could not launch 'app' with iCloud container

Tags: xcode, macos, icloud

I have an OS X app targeting 10.7 (Lion) platform. I use XCode 4.4 on a development machine where iCloud is enabled. The OS X version on this machine is 10.8 (Mountain Lion).

I have an APP ID that I enabled `iCloud` using the Developer Certificate Utility: `com.company.appname`. The utility shows a green tick next to iCloud label under description of the App ID.

From `XCode` `Target/Summary` tab I enabled `Entitlements` and added iCloud Container `com.company.appname`. Of course internally it is preceded by the team id in the Entitlements file: `teamid.com.company.appname`.

I also have a valid (green ticked) provisioning profile on my Mac with the same id:`teamid.com.company.appname`.

`Derived Data` locations is set to `Relative` from `XCode/Preferences`.

The app builds OK. But when I run it I get `"Could not launch "appname". Permission denied."` error.

If I remove the iCloud container id `com.company.appname` from `iCloud Containers` list box under Entitlements and build the app, it runs OK. But of course I cannot access iCloud container enabled for the app.

I have been working on this problem for the past 24 hours. I have read the guides; `Developing for the App Store`, `App Sandbox Design Guide`, and `Entitlement Key Reference` inside out. Yet I am stuck. What went wrong?

I am desperate and I will be grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most likely problem is that the AppID, the Entitlement and your provisioning profile do not match each other. 
This can happen easily if you experiment a lot with those settings. It should work right out of the box if you create a fresh new project with valid settings, but it might get corrupted if you convert, change or edit existing projects.

Do not forget about the 10-digit prefix of your app bundle id. This is required, esp. for iCloud Key-Value-Storage!

- Log into developer.apple.com, check the AppIDs tab
- Create an AppID if necessary
- Check the iCloud settings for this app
- Note down the exact app identifier in the form `ABCDE01234.com.domain.app`
- Switch back to Xcode, update your Provisioning Profiles and Entitlements in the "Teams" section of the "Devices" Tab in the Organizer
- Go to the project settings, select the app target and search for "Code Sign"
- Make sure the correct code signing identity is selected (see the application identifier above)
- Go to the summary tab and put in your app ID
- Open the Entitlements file and check if the right ID is in there as well.

Then it should work.
Hopefully.

**Edit:** thought it would be nice to add the link to the app id center:
https://developer.apple.com/certificates/index.action#bundlelist

Comment: Many thanks auco. Unfortunately I cannot verify these now, as I have moved on with a workaround. My workaround is: I created a proxy app to create a shortcut to my app's iCloud folder on user's desktop. This way they can load/save docs from/to cloud. The catch is there is no handling of merging real time changes (i.e changes made by iPhone while the Mac app is open and in use). So I'll have to come back to this issue and make my 'proper' fix perhaps in 1-2 months time. If by then your answer helps me to fix it then I'll definitely tick your answer. Many thanks again for your help :)